# Express a normal linear transformation as a linear combination of projections.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection

There's the following theorem:

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a normal linear transformation $(TT^{*}=T^{*}T)$. Prove there exists $E_1,...,E_k$ such that:

- $E_i^{2}=E_i$
- $E_iE_j=0$ for all $i\neq j$
- $\sum_{i}^{k} E_i = I_V$
- $\sum_{i}^{k} \lambda_i E_i = T$ where $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of T.

I would like a hint on how to prove this theorem or what is its name.

As for what I tried so far, I tried looking at $T - \lambda_i I_V$ and I also tried looking at the case where dimV=2. Couldn't make any progress.

Comment: Show that if $\lambda\neq \mu$ are the eigenvalues of $T,$ then the subspaces $\ker (T-\lambda I)$ and $\ker(T-\mu I)$ are orthogonal. Denote by $E_\lambda$ the orthogonal projection on $\ker (T-\lambda I).$ You will obtain $T=\sum_\lambda \lambda E_\lambda.$

Comment: In the above theorem we must have $\dim V < \infty.$ It is the "Spectral Theorem of normal Operators."

Comment: As the question is tagged linear algebra, I have taken for granted that $T$ is a matrix. But the conclusion holds when $\dim V$ is infinite if the range of $T$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Comment: It's called the Spectral Theorem for normal operators on a complex finite-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** Let $T : X\rightarrow X$ be a linear map on a complex inner product space $X$. Then $T$ is normal iff
$$
                 \|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|,\;\; x\in X.\;\;(\dagger)
$$
**Proof:** The proof follows from the polarization identity on $X$:
$$
          \langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3} i^n\|x+i^ny\|^2.
$$
Indeed,
$$
    \langle T^*Tx,y\rangle=\langle Tx,Ty\rangle =\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n\|T(x+i^ny)\|^2 \\
    \langle TT^*x,y\rangle=\langle T^*x,T^*y\rangle=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{3}i^n\|T^*(x+i^ny)\|^2
$$
Therefore, it follows that $T^*T=TT^*$ iff $\|Tx\|=\|T^*x\|$ for all $x\in X.\;\;\;\blacksquare$

**Lemma:** Let $T : X\rightarrow X$ be a linear map on a complex inner product space $X$. If $T$ is normal, then
$$
       \mathcal{N}(T)=\mathcal{N}(T^2)=\mathcal{N}(T^3)\cdots.
$$
**Proof:** This can be proved by induction. Suppose that $T$ is normal, and further suppose that $T^2x=0$. Then the first lemma above gives
$$
     0=\|T^2x\|=\|T^*Tx\| \implies 0=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle =\|Tx\|^2 \implies Tx=0.
$$
You can complete the argument by induction to show that $T^nx=0 \implies Tx=0$. $\;\;\blacksquare$

The conclusion that you eventually reach from this line of argument is that the minimal polynomial for a normal $T$ has no repeated roots. The Jordan canonical form for $T$ is a diagonal matrix, and you have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors for $T$. The projections onto the eigenspaces are the $E_j$ that you want.